# Python function, why did the value of `running_high` in f1 change here?

Tags: python-3.x

```
def announce_highest(who, last_score=0, running_high=0):
    def f(score0, score1):
        nonlocal running_high
        score = [score0, score1][who]
        difference = score - last_score
        if difference > running_high:
            running_high = difference
            print(f"{running_high} point(s)! That's the biggest gain yet for Player {who}")
            return announce_highest(who, score, running_high)
        return announce_highest(who, score, running_high)
    return f

f0 = announce_highest(1)
f1 = f0(12, 0)
f2 = f1(12, 11)
f2_again = f1(11, 9)
```

Here the `running_high` in f2_again is no longer 0 but becomes 11, but in f2_again, it should keep the same `running_high` value as when f1 was called for the first time, which is 0.I really can't figure it out. Can someone help me and explain this?

An understandable, detailed explanation.

Answer (score 0):

f0 is assigned `f(score0, score1)` which contains references to the enclosing function (`announce_highest`) variables with these values:

```
who: 1
last_score: 0
running_high: 0
```

Then `f0` is called with `score0 = 12` and `score1 = 0`
The result of `score = [score0, score1][who]` is

```
score = [12, 0][1]
score = 0
```

```
difference = score - last_score
difference = 0 - 0 = 0
```

and so `return announce_highest(who, score, running_high)`
is called with `return announce_highest(who=1, score=0, running_high=0)`
and then `f` is returned as before and assigned to `f1`

Now `f` is called with `score0=12` and `score1=11`
This is where the change occurs...

```
nonlocal running_high
score = [score0, score1][who]
difference = score - last_score
```

is this

```
nonlocal 0
score = [12, 11][1] = 11
difference = 11 - 0 = 11
```

and so

```
if difference > running_high:
    running_high = difference
```

```
if 11 > 0:
    running_high = 11  # CHANGE IS HERE
```

Then this is call to set up f again:

```
announce_highest(who, score, running_high)
```

```
announce_highest(1, 11, 11)
```

Finally when this is called

```
f2_again = f1(11, 9)
```

That results in

```
f(score0=11, score1=9)
```

and so this:

```
        nonlocal running_high
        score = [score0, score1][who]
        difference = score - last_score
        if difference > running_high:
```

```
        nonlocal 11
        # above is because of the earlier call to 
        # announce_highest(who=1, score=11, running_high=11)
        # which resulted in these args being set as:
        # announce_highest(who=1, last_score=11, running_high=11)  
        score = [11, 9][1] == 9
        difference = 9 - 11 = -2
        if -2 > 11:
```

Comment: My understanding is that `f1(12, 11)(12, 9) == announce_highest(1, 11, 11)(12, 9)`, do you think it is right?

Comment: When modify :                                                                                                                       ``` if difference > running_high:
            print(f"{difference} point(s)! That's the biggest gain yet for Player {who}")
            return announce_highest(who, score, difference)                                            
return announce_highest(who, score, running_high)                                                         
 ```  It work correctly. Here,`f1(12,11)` still return`announce_highest(1,11,11)`.